# Working with apache camel Bean in Quarkus framework

Tags: apache-camel, quarkus

I am trying to use apache camel with Quarkus. Previously I was using the spring-boot framework to develop camel integration. So there are lots of questions that I am still trying to figure out w.r.t. Quarkus framework.

**Regarding: Bean**

In spring-boot I could do something like this

```
@Configuration
public class JABXContextConfig {

    @Bean
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller() throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext  = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyPOJO.class );
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        return jaxbUnmarshaller;
    }
}
```

and then I could inject it into the class using DI

```
@Component
public class MyRestServiceRoute extends RouteBuilder {

   private final JaxbDataFormat jaxb;

   @Autowired
   public MyRestServiceRoute(JaxbDataFormat jaxb) throws Exception{
      this.jaxb = jaxb;
   }
   ....
      
 }
```

QUESTION:

1. How can I do the same in the Quarkus framework?
   P.S> I tried replacing @Configuration with @ApplicationScoped and @Bean with @Dependent but it's not working.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I recommend taking a read through the Quarkus CDI documentation:

https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi

https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference

There's also a basic overview of using CDI to configure Camel:

https://camel.apache.org/camel-quarkus/latest/user-guide/bootstrap.html#_cdi

https://camel.apache.org/camel-quarkus/latest/user-guide/cdi.html

In your examples, `@Bean` could be replaced by a producer method like:

```
public class JaxbDataFormatProducer {

    @ApplicationScoped
    JaxbDataFormat jaxbDataFormat() {
        return new JaxbDataFormat();
    }
}
```

And the `@Autowired` constructor argument might look like this (If there’s only one constructor then there's actually no need for `@Inject`):

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyRestServiceRoute extends BaseRouteBuilder {

   private final JaxbDataFormat jaxb;

   @Inject
   public MyRestServiceRoute(JaxbDataFormat jaxb) throws Exception{
      super(properties);
      this.jaxb = jaxb;
   }
      
 }
```

Comment: Hi James,  I tried what you advised but getting the following error.     ` Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
 [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.JaxbDataFormat and qualifiers [@Default]`

Comment: I updated the example so that the producer method returns a JaxbDataFormat instance. If you need to customise it in some way, you can do it in that method.